# How to extract forecast from predict in R?

Tags: r, predict

I am running VAR on a time series with multiple locations. Suppose loc1, loc2 and loc3 are the column names of the time series data.

```
fitVAR = VAR(data,p=order,type = "both", ic = "AIC") 
pred = predict(fitVAR,n.ahead = L)
```

I know that I can get the forecasts by `pred$fcst$loc1[,1]` etc. But suppose I want to write a function to do this which takes location names as a input variable(eg, `LOC=c("loc1","loc2","loc3"))`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lapply` like this:

```
 lapply(predict(pp)$fcst[LOC],'[',,1)
```

For example:

```
data(Canada)
fit <- VAR(Canada, p = 2, type = "none")
LOC <- c('e','U')
lapply(predict(fit)$fcst[LOC],'[',,'fcst') 
lapply(predict(fit)$fcst[LOC],'[',,1)
$e
 [1] 962.3490 962.7852 963.1305 963.4016 963.6116 963.7742 
     963.9023 964.0081 964.1026 964.1954

$U
 [1] 6.764097 6.751969 6.804301 6.900299 7.030548 7.184748 
     7.353441 7.528150 7.701521 7.867432
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using:

```
locs <- sapply(pred$fcst[LOC], function (k) k[ , 1])
```

The idea is that `pred$fcst` is a named list. You have put the names you want in `LOC`. Now we can collect the elements whose names are in `LOC` and then extract the first column from each into `locs`.